Visual Studio Extension how to persists data between sessions
I'm developing Visual Studio 2022 Extension and would like to make accessible some data from the previous start of the extension and Visual Studio and the next starts.
E.g. produce some license information or user-specific configurations and would like that they should be accessible during the next extension start. This data shouldn't be available on the Settings window due to the technical character of it.
Thank you in advance.

You can use a file to persistently store session information. Take a look at my answer. :)

You can use the below steps to store and get data.
1. Define your configuration class:
public class ExtensionConfig
{
    public string LicenseKey { get; set; }
    // Add other configuration properties here
}

2. Saving the configuration to a file:
var config = new ExtensionConfig { LicenseKey = "YourLicenseKey" };
string appDataPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
string configPath = Path.Combine(appDataPath, "YourExtensionName", "config.json");

// Ensure the directory exists
Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(configPath));

File.WriteAllText(configPath, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(config));

3. Loading the configuration from a file:
string appDataPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
string configPath = Path.Combine(appDataPath, "YourExtensionName", "config.json");

if (File.Exists(configPath))
{
    var configText = File.ReadAllText(configPath);
    var config = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExtensionConfig>(configText);
    // Use the config object as needed
}

By the way, if you want to make it more secure, you can define encryption and decryption steps.

Yep, thank you I finally used the same approach and store in file in users data folder
